# Collapse nav on scroll, but also start collapsed when page anchors are used

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a collapsing nav that works nicely on scroll (adds class that fixes height of nav). However, if I use an anchor to jump to another part of the page, the nav starts expanded. In Chrome the nav immediately collapses, but Firefox waits for scroll before collapsing. Is there some way I can start with the nav collapsed in this situation? Here's what I'm currently using:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Javascript to check the scrollTop after a small delay and trigger the handler.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $(window).triggerHandler('scroll');
    }
}, 500);
```